# What complexity class is this ciruit problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability, circuits

I'm exploring an algorithm that solves k-SAT.  It uses a ton of preprocessing, so I'm thinking that this will be a circuit bounds.

Without knowing the runtime, I speculate on how quickly it will solve k-SAT instances.  It will either solve all instances of k-SAT with probability $p$, or it won't be able to solve any instances.  The runtime is based on $p$.  Essentially, it runs in quasi-polynomial time.

So essentially, what we have is an algorithm that runs in time $2^{O((\log{n})^{c_1})}\cdot O(c_2 + q)$, and solves all instances with probability $\frac{2^q-1}{2^q}$, or it can't solve any instances.  Here, $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants.

It also requires space polynomial in $q$.

I'm trying to find what complexity class this is, and what is known about it.

**SOME NOTES**

Just to ensure I've described this correctly, I have an algorithm that either solves all instances, or it can't solve any.  We can say it uses $2^{2^n}$ preprocessing.  Then, it runs in time that is quasi-polynomial multiplied by a function of $q$.

**THE QUESTION, AGAIN**

What complexity class is this, and what is known about it?

Comment: Your terminology is a bit off. You write, "which complexity class is this?", but you don't seem to be defining one. You talk about algorithms, but *problems* go into complexity classes. Also, what exactly is your random experiment? Picking an algorithm (from which class?) at random?

Comment: @Raphael:  Sorry, I'll try to explain.  I'm really talking about a k-SAT algorithm, and I'm trying to find how to describe it in terms of things like complexity classes, but I guess I need a different way to describe it.  The algorithm uses a data structure to help it solve the k-SAT problem, which it can either solve all instances for a particular $n$ variables, $m$ clauses, and $k$, or none at all.  It can solve everything with probability $p^\alpha, p>1/2$, and the time and space requirements grow linearly with $\alpha$.  I was trying to find if this is a new result, which it seems to be.

Comment: @Raphael: The random experiment is picking some additional values at random, to add to the data structure, which helps it to solve all problems (in the k-SAT problem class with a given $n$ and $m$) with increased probability.

Comment: Increasing $\alpha$ makes that result increasingly useless. $\:$ What's more interesting is how $\hspace{1.24 in}$ the resource requirements grow as $\alpha$ goes to zero. $\:$ If that growth rate is slow enough, $\hspace{1.06 in}$ then your algorithm may place k-SAT in [QP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:Q#qp)/[quasipoly](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:P#ppoly). $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer:  Sorry, I wrote those comments in haste - it should be with probability $(1-p)^\alpha, p<1/2$.  What I'm trying to convey is that, from what I understand, with high probability, we can find a circuit that solves all instances of k-SAT with given $m$ and $n$ in pseudopolynomial time and space.  Wouldn't these circuits be significant results?

Comment: ... that's ... exactly equivalent to your previous comment. $\:$ Do you mean "_except_ with probability $p^{\alpha}$? $\hspace{.3 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer:  I'm sorry you're probably losing confidence in me - but yes, I mean except with probability $p^\alpha$.

Comment: In that case, do you mean "except with probability $p^{\alpha}$, it can solve everything" or "for every instance, [it can solve that instance except with probability $p^{\alpha}$]"? $\;$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18856/discussion-between-matt-groff-and-ricky-demer).

Comment: (I just got reminded that for some reason, the site won't let me log in to chat.) $\hspace{1.62 in}$ Note that, unless you mean it always works, "the first case that" I mention does _not_ follow $\hspace{.85 in}$ from "It solves particular instances in the same way.". $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: We don't have to use chat - I wish I could help with that, though.  Anyways, if it can solve one instance of k-SAT with parameters $k$, $m$, and $n$, it can solve all instances of k-SAT with these parameters.

Comment: Those circuits would be significant results. $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer:  Thank you very much for the confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the probability is over the randomized preprocessing and $p > 0$, by fixing the correct random choice you get a circuit of size $S = O(2^{\log^{O(1)} n} q^{O(1)})$ for $k$-SAT. The corresponding complexity class is non-uniform circuits of size $S$. If, for example, $q$ is quasipolynomial ($2^{\log^{O(1)}n}$), the you get a non-uniform circuit of quasipolynomial size.

We usually don't care too much about the time required to construct the circuit unless it is very low.

Comment: Thanks, Dr. Filmus.  Maybe you can answer another question related to this.  See the comments to Dr. Ryan William's answer to my question here:  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9654/are-quasi-polynomial-sized-circuits-for-3-sat-trivial     I'm really just trying to find if I have a useful circuit algorithm...